# Disable MailChimp popup from Mobile

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, mailchimp

I want to disable my MailChimp popup from mobile to avoid Google penalties. This is used to embed the popup on my site.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/unique-methods/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.dojoRequire(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { 
    L.start({
        "baseUrl": "mc.us19.list-manage.com",
        "uuid": "0c8ced88887c6dc86871c25e2",
        "lid": "756660c309",
        "uniqueMethods": true
    }) 
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: I believe the below code includes the correct class to hide the MailChimp popup from mobile.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 .mc-banner { display: none !important; }
```